# Mount volume into docker container without noexec option

Tags: docker, docker-compose

As i recon, docker (docker-compose also) mounts volumes into container with noexec option, so i cant start any program from inside mounted directory.

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.development
    command: sh -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && /app/bin/rails s -b 0.0.0.0"
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app:cached
```

So, inside container we can see /app mounted like
`/dev/sdb1 on /app type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,data=ordered)`

Is that exist some way to mount volume without this option? 
I have search in documentation, but found nothing

Answer (score 5):

Listen up all! Dismiss!

I shoot my own leg. 
This problem was because i moved my /home and /var/lib/docker to dedicated partitions of disk (because lack of disk space), and by default they was mounted by linux with noexec option.

Docker just retranslate that inside container